# How to format a JSON structure in Java

Tags: java, json

I want to create a JSON like this using Java:

```
"foo": {
         "key1": "value1",
         "key2": "value2",
         }
```

I know how to create a key value json or a json array, but I don't know how to create a `structure` like this.

What can I try next?

Comment: your example is invalid json. Json structure should start with { or [.

Comment: Did You use a library? key1 & key2 are properties of bean, keys of map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems your values are more relative to `Map` of java. So you need
>   to find how to convert `Map` into json with java. Usually json
>   processing is performing with frameworks such json and gson. However
>   you can do it manually with `StringBuilder` class. Refer following
>   example to manually create json with java.

**Manually create json with java**

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "value1");
    map.put("key2", "value2");

    //convert it to json maually
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("\"foo\":{");
        builder.append("\n");
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        builder.append("\t");
        builder.append("\"").append(key).append("\"");
        builder.append(":");
        builder.append("\"").append(map.get(key)).append("\"");
        builder.append(",");
        builder.append("\n");
    }
    builder.append("\t}");

    String json = builder.toString();
    System.out.println(json);
```

**output:**

```
"foo":{
    "key2":"value2",
    "key1":"value1",
    }
```

**Follow example below to convert `Map<K,V>` into json with jackson.**

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "value1");
    map.put("key2", "value2");

    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);
    System.out.println(json);
```